# How to group by and count number of none missing values for each column in group in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandasql

I have the following datadrame

```
user_id  var  qualified_date    loyal_date
  1       1      2017-01-17     2017-02-03
  2       1      2017-01-03     2017-01-13
  3       1      2017-01-11      NaT
  4       1       NaT            NaT
  5       1       NaT            NaT
  6       2      2017-01-15      2017-02-14
  7       2      2017-01-07      NaT
  8       2      2017-01-23      2017-02-18
  9       2      2017-01-25      NaT
  10      2      2017-01-11      2017-03-01
```

I need to groupby this dataframe by values in 'Var' and count the number of non missing values then for each of 'qualified_date' and 'engaged_date' columns. I can do it for each column seperately and put them manually in a dataframe, but i am looking for a groupby approach or soething similar where i can automatically come to a new DF than has values in 'var' as index and for for two columns that show count of non missing values for every group.

Like this

```
var  qualified_count loyal_count
 1       xx            xx
 2       xx            xx
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`DF.GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) which includes only Non-`NaN` entries while counting. So, you can let `var` be the grouped key and then aggregate the counts respectively for the two selected columns of the `DF` as shown:

```
cols = ['qualified_date', 'loyal_date']
df.groupby('var')[cols].agg('count').add_suffix("_count").reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks  this is exactly what i am looking for, is there any way to pivot it and have, 'var 1' , 'var 2' as column names and 'qualified_date_count' and 'loyal_date_count' as indexes? can we edit the code or i need to ask a new question?

Comment: Just remove the `.reset_index()` portion and transpose the `DF`. You would have to handle additional formatting though to your column names.